# mouse wheel press down input to shift hotkey

Tags: javascript

I'm new learner of JavaScript and need help with how can I change the mouse wheel input. When the user press it down to hotkey shift?

For example if the user presses the mouse wheel in any website sending ((shift)) value to the browser.

Comment: You can't make this happen for all websites. What you can do is intercept that event in your own page(s) and proceed accordingly.

Comment: @ScottMarcus - a web extension could make it happen for all websites

Comment: True, but I am assuming a "new learner" for JavaScript wasn't asking about extensions. My bad.

Comment: thanks guys for fast reply.and im using tampermonkey to run my script so i can include any website but i need like if condition for example in java we write 

((if (evt.getWheelRotation() >= 1)
                    {

                        }))
is there anything like this in javascript?

Comment: still not get any answer